# Practical insightful time domain functions

Tags: fft, autocorrelation, time-domain, linear-prediction

This question might be a little bit different, but i am having hard time to find some sort of a list/book/website/advice, with very practical time domain functions that ***provides useful insgihts*** for a series of numbers in time domain (frequencies of less than 1Hz)

Examples - *FFT* to find periods in a noisy signal, *Autocorrelation*  for finding an interesting correlations between 2 curves.

Very curious to know about more, maybe more functionality about *prediction* and information that is useful and critical in real life.

Comment: It's really not obvious which exact kind of topic(s) you want to focus on? Signals? Systems? Filters? Harmonic Analysis (CTFT,DTFT, DFT, DCT, FFT)? Random Processes? Estimation? Prediction? Adaptive Systems? Modulation? Feedback? Control? Which exact topic(s) you want books on?

Comment: Thanks, sorry. Say I am getting time series from many sources, say temperature sensors, voltages, lights, motors speed, etc. I would like to find interesting connections between them, predictions, things I can’t see in bare eyes, actionable insights

Comment: ok then how you want to process them? what's the pupose of the processing? signal estimation? spectral analysis? linear predicton? filtering? Ok so you want **correlative** analysis...

Answer (score 2):

I've written a series of three blog articles about three families of time domain frequency calculation for single pure tones, real or complex.  You can find them here:

- [Exact Near Instantaneous Frequency Formulas Best at Peaks (Part 1)](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1051.php)
- [Exact Near Instantaneous Frequency Formulas Best at Peaks (Part 2)](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1056.php)
- [Exact Near Instantaneous Frequency Formulas Best at Zero Crossings](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1074.php)

The applicability in DSP is rather limited, but if this is what you are doing, these are the formulas you want.